# Inconsistent cursor results when looping over databases

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, cursors

I have several databases named very similar (my-db-1, my-db-2, my-db-3, my-db-4). I want to execute the same stored procedure on each of these databases. I decided to use cursors. However, I am getting some strange issues. First here is my simple code that I am executing through SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

```
DECLARE @db_cursor CURSOR 
DECLARE @name varchar(255)
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000)

SET @db_cursor = CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name LIKE 'my-db-%'

OPEN @db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM @db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN  

    SET @Sql = 'Use [' + @name + ']; PRINT DB_NAME();'
    exec sp_sqlexec @Sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM @db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE @db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE @db_cursor
```

Executing this multiple times in a row within 2 seconds, I get strange results:

Execution1:

```
my-db-1
my-db-2
my-db-3
my-db-4
```

Execution2:

```
my-db-1
my-db-2
```

Execution3:

```
my-db-1
my-db-2
my-db-3
my-db-4
```

Execution4:

```
my-db-1
```

It seems like its completely random. Sometimes I'll get all 4 databases to print after 10 executions. Sometimes after just 2 executions only 1 database will get printed.

This SQL is executing on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600: ) through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1600.1

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your cursor as `FAST_FORWARD`.

The default is an updateable cursor and these required update locks probably conflict with another process accessing `sys.databases`

Ref.: [DECLARE CURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: That seems to fix it. Thank you.