# Inconsistent results from TSQL cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

I've got a query that uses a cursor to insert data into my database. The weird thing is that the query runs the 1st time ( SSMS > Execute ), but if I run it a second time, the part with the cursor does not execute.

However - If i then hit 'debug' I can debug and the whole query executes just fine. Right after that it works just fine once more and then, again, only the first insert script executes.

I tried the FAST_FORWARD as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048147/inconsistent-cursor-results-when-looping-over-databases) but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any suggestions?

```
/** Declarations **************************************************/
DECLARE @TemplateFileName varchar(200)
DECLARE @TemplatePreviewFileName varchar(200)
DECLARE @TemplateId int
DECLARE @CompanyId int
DECLARE CompanyCursor cursor FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT [CmpId] from SetCompany
/******************************************************************/

/** Set template name here ****************************************/
SET @TemplateFileName           = 'Template_2'
SET @TemplatePreviewFileName    = 'Template_2'
/******************************************************************/

/******************************************************************/
INSERT INTO ... etc
SET @TemplateId = @@IDENTITY;
Open CompanyCursor

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN       
        IF(@CompanyId IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Adding template ' + @TemplateFileName + ' with id ' + convert(varchar, @TemplateId) + ' to company ' + convert(varchar, @CompanyId);
            INSERT INTO .... etc
            PRINT 'OK';
        END
        Fetch NEXT FROM CompanyCursor INTO @CompanyId
END
CLOSE CompanyCursor;
DEALLOCATE CompanyCursor;
```

Running the 'first' time, I get:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Adding template Template_2.frx with id 2272 to company 10

(1 row(s) affected)
OK
Adding template Template_2.frx with id 2272 to company 11

(1 row(s) affected)
OK
Adding template Template_2.frx with id 2272 to company 12

(1 row(s) affected)
OK
Adding template Template_2.frx with id 2272 to company 13

(1 row(s) affected)
OK
Adding template Template_2.frx with id 2272 to company 14

(1 row(s) affected)
OK
```

Second time, only this:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

And indeed, the insert inside the cursor did not run.

Comment: Even better solution: avoid that messy cursor altogether! :-)

Comment: @marc_s - how do you suggest I do it?

Comment: just a single `INSERT INTO ..... SELECT ..... FROM  .....` - no need for a cursor at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After

```
Open CompanyCursor
```

Add

```
FETCH NEXT FROM CompanyCursor
INTO @CompanyId
```

Comment: Thank! That solved it. But then why does it run the first time?